# No consigo leer los resultados de una consulta MySQL con SUM() y UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysqli, bucles, multiselect, union

es mi primer post en este sitio y no soy un desarrollador profesional así que tenerme paciencia pls. Estoy haciendo una simple pagina la que necesito que me devuelva un resultado SUM() de 4 columnas de una consulta con doble SELECT usando UNION ALL de 2 tablas que contienen importes/comisiones. Su estructura es simple: ID (afco_00), NIF (afco_01), identificador de back office (afco_02), importe con IVA (afco_03), importe sin IVA (afco_04), IVA (afco_05), IRPF (afco_06), estatus (afco_07), TIME STAMP (afco_08) y observaciones (afco_09).

PASO 1.- Primero realizo una llamada 1 tabla para obtener datos del cliente con lo que no tengo ningun problema a ni error, luego imprimo o uso los resultados recibidos y extraídos con extract(); sin problemas.

```
$result_b = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT * FROM PersYY01 WHERE pers_05='$user';");
$row_b=mysqli_fetch_array($result_b);
extract($row_b, EXTR_SKIP);
$nif=$row_b["pers_01"];
```

PASO 2.- Realizo la segunda llamada a 2 tablas con las comisiones (una del año en curso 2021 y otra de año anterior 2020) y es donde en ambos SELECT uso SUM() para obtener una sola fila con la suma de las columnas que contienen los importes que son las afco_03, afco_04, afco_05 y afco_06. Lo he probado en mi base de datos y me genera sin problemas y con los resultados correctos la nueva tabla con solo dos filas y con la suma de cada columna.

```
$result_c = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT SUM(afco_03), SUM(afco_04), SUM(afco_05), SUM(afco_06) FROM AfcoYY01_".date("Y")." WHERE afco_01='$nif' AND afco_02='PENDIENTE' UNION ALL SELECT SUM(afco_03), SUM(afco_04), SUM(afco_05), SUM(afco_06) FROM AfcoYY01_".date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"))." WHERE afco_01='$nif' AND afco_02='PENDIENTE';");
```

Por si a caso he añadido este código temporal para asegurarme de que la llamada me devuelve el resultado cuando ejecuto la pagina y me devuelve el numero de filas y de las columnas en cada una.

```
$num_c=mysqli_num_rows($result_c);
$num_campos=mysqli_num_fields($result_c);
echo $num_c."</br>";
echo $num_campos;
```

Así que hasta este punto parece estar todo bien, la llamada SQL funciona, genera una tabla con resultados y estos son correctos.

PASO 3.- Aquí es donde parece que tengo el problema, es decir cuando quiero extraer estos datos e imprimirlos en mi pagina. Este es el código del bucle WHILE que estoy usando y que no funciona.

```
while($row_c=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_c)) {
print "Comision bruta: ".$row_c["afco_03"]."</br> Comision neta: ".$row_c["afco_04"]."</br> IVA: ".$row_c["afco_05"]."</br> IRPF: ".$row_c["afco_06"]."</br>"; 
}
```

Cuando quito el SUM() de la llamada SELECT a la base de datos me funciona perfectamente, pero al añadir el SUM() en la llamada es cuando deja de funcionar y ya he probado de todo, lo he intentado con mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_c), con mysqli_fetch_array($result_c) y no soy capaz de leer el array con los datos de la tabla. No se que estoy haciendo mal pero estoy a 99% convencido que es en este punto donde esta el problema porque como decía, si quito el SUM() la web funciona, si lo añado entonces deja de funcionar esta parte y no me imprime los resultados de la tabla. Como si la tabla después del SUM() tuviera algun otro formato o como si debiera usar algun tipo de array especial para ello, no lo se.

Si a alguien se le ocurre una solución para ello le agradezco su ayuda.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu problema es simplemente de nombres de campos.. proba tus querys en un administrador de base de datos (por ejemplo phpmyadmin) y fijate que los nombres de las columnas cambian!!!! usa algo asi para arreglarlo sum(campo) AS elnombrequequeres.... y listo.. fin del problema...

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Faltaba corregir el nombre de las variables en el WHILE por SUM(afco_03), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede en tu código, es que debes de poner un `as` después del `SUM(valor)`

Ejemplo:

```
 <?php 

 $sql = $conex->query("SELECT SUM(afco_03) as suma FROM ...");

 $fetch = $sql->fetch_array();

 echo $fetch['suma'];

 ?>
```